# mysql str_to_date within before insert trigger

Tags: mysql

I'm working with an a timestamp from application logs in the format of "Apr 28 09:54:46", this is the format of the value in NEW.timestamp below.  Trying to parse with a trigger before insert in the following fashion.

```
CREATE DEFINER=`xxxxx`@`%` 
TRIGGER `<trigger_name>` 
BEFORE 
INSERT ON `<table_name>` FOR EACH ROW 
SET NEW.timestamp = STR_TO_DATE('NEW.timestamp', '%d %b %Y %H:%i:%S'), NEW.Id = UUID();
```

This is returning a null value.  If anyone can shed some light on this it would be much appreciated.

Comment: If you changed it from before insert to after insert, do you have the same problem?

Comment: The format of the timestamp being what it is, then MySQL does not understand that as datetime which is the definition of the field.  So, I cannot insert the data as it to do an operation after insert.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
STR_TO_DATE('NEW.timestamp', '%d %b %Y %H:%i:%S')
```

is wrong. Do not quote `NEW.timestamp`

Sorry I can't put it in comment, there you can't see the backticks.

Use:

```
STR_TO_DATE(`NEW`.`timestamp`, '%d %b %Y %H:%i:%S')
```

I have found the problem. Mysql checks the argument before is in trigger. So I have add a dummy column 'tmp' varchar(32) and use this.

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`%` TRIGGER myt
BEFORE INSERT ON times 
FOR EACH ROW 
SET NEW.ts = STR_TO_DATE(NEW.tmp, '%d %b %Y %H:%i:%S'), NEW.Id = UUID(),NEW.tmp='';

INSERT INTO times (id,tmp) VALUES (2,'28 Apr 2016 14:34:46');
```

Comment: Bernd,  Thanks for the response.  However, I get the same result using the format suggested.

Comment: Interesting item is that this works from CLI, but not in the trigger.

Comment: in your sample date string is no YEAR ?  "Apr 28 09:54:46" - is this correct ? or post the correct one

Comment: My apologies.  Here is the context of the attempting to insert directly pasted...I was typing before: 28 Apr 2016 14:34:46

Comment: just curious...how does the check MySQL does result in null value?

Comment: this seems like a MySQL bug

Comment: No no, its not a bug. the Argument in the trigger is from the Feld type. so is it from type date you got a date and cant mysql not convert the string to the date it will give you NULL. this 100% OK